# An equivalence relation on regions of the plane.

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, analytic-geometry

Let $R\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the set of all "horizontal sections" $H_R =${$Rb|b\in\mathbb{R}$}, where $Rb=${$a\in\mathbb{R} | (a,b)\in R$}. Similarly consider the set of "vertical sections" of $R$, $V_R =${$ aR|a\in\mathbb{R}$} where $aR=${$ b\in\mathbb{R} | (a,b)\in R$}.  Now define the equivalence relation on $\wp (\mathbb{R^2})$ such that $R \sim S$ if, and only if, $H_R=H_S$ and $V_R=V_S$.

QUESTION: What is the equivalence class of a disk?

Comment: I have some troubles understanding the definition of the sets $H_R$ and $V_R$. Are they the projection of $R$ on the $x$ and $y$ axis, respectively? If so, I think the equivalence class of a disk would be the set of all figures of constant width inscribed in the disk.

Comment: Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be any continuous, monotone decreasing function such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$. Let $R_0$ be the region bounded by $y=f(x)$ and the coordinate axes, and let $R$ be the region, symmetric about the origin, obtained by reflecting $R_0$ in the axes. Every such $R$ is in the equivalence class of the unit disk, and my guess is that nothing else is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote with $\pi_1,\pi_2: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ the coordinate projections.

First, let me make explicit what exactly the elusive sets $H_R$ and $V_R$ are (since I tripped into a pitfall about that earlier on).

We have that $H_R = \{Rb: b \in \Bbb R\}$, where $Rb = \{a \in \Bbb R: (a,b)\in\Bbb R\}$. In terms of the projections, this comes down to $H_R = \{\pi_1[R \cap \pi_2^{-1}(b)]: b \in \Bbb R\}$. We can imagine this as the sets we see when moving a horizontal slit over the set $R$.

Similarly, $V_R = \{\pi_2[R \cap \pi_1^{-1}(a)]: a \in \Bbb R\}$, and it can be imagined as the subsets of $\Bbb R$ obtained from sliding over $R$ with a vertical slit.

---

For finding the equivalence class, let us reduce to the entirely generic case of the (closed) unit disk $B$.

Then we observe that $H_B = V_B = \{[-a,a]: a \in [0,1]\}$. The apparent symmetry allows us to restrict attention to the upper right quadrant, since $R$ will have to be extended in a unique way, by said symmetry. We will hereafter drop distinction between $R$ and the intersection of $R$ with the upper right quadrant.

The conditions $H_R = H_B$ and $V_R = V_B$ imply that for each $r,s \in [0,1]$, there are unique $a, b$ with $\pi_1[R \cap \pi_2^{-1}(s)] = [0,a]$ and $\pi_2[R \cap\pi_1^{-1}(r)] = [0,b]$. We define mappings $i_H, i_V$ by $i_H(s) =a$ and $i_V(r)=b$.

Now suppose that for given $a$, we find an $s \in [0,1]$ such that $i_H(s) = a$. If for some $s' > s$ we would have that $i_H(s') = a' > a$, then for $i_V(a')$ to be an interval, we would need $(a',s) \in R$ since $s \le s'$, contradicting that $a' > a$ and $i_H(s)=a$.

This contradiction provides us with the information that $s \le s'$ implies $i_H(s) \supseteq i_H(s')$. A similar reasoning can be applied to obtain that $r \le r'$ implies $i_V(r) \supseteq i_V(r')$.

Now what happens when $s < s'$ and $i_H(s) = i_H(s')$? Then $i_V(i_H(s)) = s'$, while for $a' > i_H(s)$ we have necessarily that $i_V(a') < s$; the above analysis hence renders it impossible that there exists an $a''$ such that $s < i_V(a'') < s'$, contradicting our assumptions.

Therefore, both $r \mapsto i_V(r)$ and $s \mapsto i_H(s)$ are strictly decreasing surjections, and by the above argument they are also injective; A cursory remark is that $i_H(i_V(r))=r$ and $i_V(i_H(s)) = s$ for all $r,s$.

In conclusion, $B \sim R$ iff $R$ is the area below a strictly decreasing bijection $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, reflected first the horizontal, then the vertical coordinate.

---

Real analysis tells us that on intervals, "strictly decreasing bijection" is synonymous with "continuous injection mapping endpoints to opposite endpoints". Thus this answer matches [Brian M. Scott's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105365#comment247148_105365).

Comment: I think you got it wrong: $H_R$ and $V_R$ are not intervals, but *sets* of intervals.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I'm confident that this new attempt, now with the correct definitions, settles the question. Thanks again.